# Hartl ROR Tutorial Chapter 10 Rspec tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I am nearing the end of the Hartl rails tutorial and have run into an Rspec problem I can't seem to figure out. The 2 tests introduced at http://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts#sec-access_control Listing 10.23 are failing with the following messages:

```
Failures:

  1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the create action 
 Failure/Error: before { post microposts_path }
 ActionController::ParameterMissing:
   param is missing or the value is empty: micropost
 # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:20:in `micropost_params'
 # ./app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:5:in `create'
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:107:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the destroy action 
 Failure/Error: before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template microposts/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
     * "/Users/name/Sites/sample_app/app/views"
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:112:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message('Invalid') }
      it { should_not have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should have_link('Help',            href: help_path) }
      it { should have_link('Home',            href: root_path) }
      it { should have_link('Sign in',         href: signin_path) }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before { sign_in user }

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Users',       href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',    href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "create new user goes to root_path" do
        before { visit new_user_path }
        it { should_not have_title('Sign up') }
      end

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "as admin user"
      let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin) }
        before { sign_in admin, no_capybara: true }

      describe "prohibit admin for self deletion" do
        specify do
          expect { delete user_path(admin) }.not_to change(User, :count).by(-1)
      end
    end


    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }


      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            expect(page).to have_title('Edit user')
          end

          describe "when signing in again" do
            before do
              click_link "Sign out"
              visit signin_path
              fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
              fill_in "Password", with: user.password
              click_button "Sign in"
            end

            it "should render the default (profile) page" do
              expect(page).to have_title(user.name)
            end
          end
        end
      end

       describe "in the Microposts controller" do

        describe "submitting to the create action" do
          before { post microposts_path }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
          before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end

      describe "in the Users controller" do

        describe "visiting the user index" do
          before { visit users_path }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "visiting the edit page" do
          before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
          it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        end

        describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            expect(page).to have_title('Edit user')
          end
        end
      end

        describe "submitting to the update action" do
          before { patch user_path(user) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
        end
      end

      describe "as non-admin user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      before { sign_in non_admin, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
        before { delete user_path(user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
   end
 end

  describe "as wrong user" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
      before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }

      describe "submitting a GET request to the Users#edit action" do
        before { get edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response.body).not_to match(full_title('Edit user')) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end

      describe "submitting a PATCH request to the Users#update action" do
        before { patch user_path(wrong_user) }
        specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(root_url) }
      end
    end
  end
```

For number 1) it seems like it looking for a micropost yet it should by pass that completely and just go to the signin page (as you can see below the micropost controller has the before action setup to check if the user is signed in and if they aren't to forward them to the sign in page... this applies for all actions).

For number 2) it is looking for a view that doesn't and will never exist? Why is it doing this? How do I stop this behaviour.

It seems like the app is bypassing the before filter in the microposts controller?

Here is my microposts_controller.rb:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :signed_in_user 

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end
 end
```

& my signed_in_user and sign_in? methods that sit in my sessions_helper.rb

```
def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

Any insights into why my tests are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Don't know how I missed it but I was still signed in when running the test. Signing out before running the Microposts non signed in user post and destroy tests was all that was needed. I added the signout code in the authenication_pages_spec.rb as follows:

```
describe "in the Microposts controller" do
        before do

        click_link "Sign out"

        describe "submitting to the create action" do
          before { post microposts_path }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end

        describe "submitting to the destroy action" do
          before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
          specify { expect(response).to redirect_to(signin_path) }
        end
      end
     end
```